# Null object not so elegantly handled after JSON.deserialize()

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

According to [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257291/elegantly-handle-the-null-object-check-after-json-deserialize/257302), returning a blank list should handle nulls.  But in my case it still complains that it's expecting something but found null.  Here is my class:

```
public class PersonProfile {

        public class PhoneDetails {
            public String cust_phone_id;
            public String phone_type;
            public String phone_type_primary_ind;
            public String phone_number;
            public String solicit_phone;
            public String mobile_text_messages_allowed;
        }

        public List<RECORD> RECORD;

        public class AddressDetails {
            public String cust_address_id;
            public String address_type;
            public String primary_ind_address;
            public String address_type_primary_ind;
            public String street_addr_1;
            public String street_addr_2;
            public String city;
            public String state;
            public String zip;
            public String country;
            public String company_address_ind;
            public String solicit_mail;
        }

        public class RECORD {
            public String cust_name_id;
            public String email_id;
            public String email_type;
            public String email_addr;
            public String primary_ind_email;
            public String solicit_email;
            public String name_type;
            public String name_first;
            public String name_middle;
            public String name_last;
            public String full_name;
            public String name_suffix;
            public String name_title;
            public String company_name;
            public String gender;
            public String add_datetime;
            public String upd_datetime;
            public List<PhoneDetails> PhoneDetails { get {
                return PhoneDetails == null ? new List<PhoneDetails>() : PhoneDetails;
                } set;
            }
            public List<AddressDetails> AddressDetails { get {
                return AddressDetails == null ? new List<AddressDetails>() : AddressDetails;
                } set;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "RECORD": [
        {
            "cust_name_id": "3594720",
            "name_type": "I",
            "name_first": "Count",
            "name_middle": null,
            "name_last": "Ravioli",
            "full_name": "Count Ravioli",
            "name_suffix": null,
            "name_title": null,
            "company_name": null,
            "add_datetime": "2020-01-15T09:59:20.173-05:00",
            "upd_datetime": "2020-01-15T09:59:20.173-05:00",
            "PhoneDetails": [
                null
            ],
            "AddressDetails": [
                {
                    "cust_address_id": "4539116",
                    "address_type": "H",
                    "primary_ind_address": "Y",
                    "address_type_primary_ind": "Y",
                    "street_addr_1": null,
                    "street_addr_2": null,
                    "city": null,
                    "company_address_ind": "N",
                    "solicit_mail": "N"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is how i call it:

```
public static IntegrationWebService.Response createProfileRegistration(RestRequest req, RestResponse res) {

    String errorMessage;

    Exception exceptionResult;
    Boolean errorsFound = false;

    try {
        PersonProfile  profile = new PersonProfile ();
        profile = (PersonProfile ) System.JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(), PersonProfile.class);

        for (PersonProfile.RECORD p : profile.RECORD){      

        //Do a bunch of things...
       }

     }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('ERROR: ' + e);
        String exType = e.getTypeName();
        String exMessage = e.getMessage();

        exceptionResult = e;
        errorsFound = true;        
    }
}
```

this line throws the error, however, if i remove the null and pass an empty array it doesn't complain at all and processes the record.  How can i properly handle nulls without having to pass empty arrays?

```
 profile = (PersonProfile ) System.JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(), PersonProfile.class);
```

The error is: `"errorMessage": "Expected PersonProfile.PhoneDetails but found null at [line:16, column:5]"`

Comment: an empty array would be the proper semantics or simply a value of `null` for property `PhoneDetails`. Do you have control over the input JSON?

Comment: Yes, i do have control of the input.  So best practice would be to pass a blank array instead of null?

Comment: yep --- either empty array or no value for the property at all (and your getter transforms to an empty array)

Comment: @cropredy You should have added an answer to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have control over the input JSON, there are three ways to express an empty list:

**Option 1**

```
{
"RECORD": [
      {
        ...
        "PhoneDetails": [],
        ...
      }
   ]
 }
```

in which case the value of the property `PhoneDetails` will be an empty list of `PhoneDetails` objects *(as an aside, this inner class should be called `PhoneDetail` as it is an object of a single Phone)*

**Option 2**

```
{
"RECORD": [
      {
        ...
        "PhoneDetails": null,
        ...
      }
   ]
 }
```

**Option 3** - simply omit the PhoneDetails property altogether in the payload - it will deserialize as null into the `PhoneDetails` property within the parent `RECORD` object.

In Option 2 and 3, you need a getter on the `PhoneDetails` property as you have coded in the OP:

```
public List<PhoneDetails> PhoneDetails { 
   get {
        return PhoneDetails == null ? new List<PhoneDetails>() : PhoneDetails;
        } set;
}
```

As a matter of defensive programming, I would assume Option 3 in the Apex and that Options 1-2-3 are all acceptable and will deserialize correctly. Anything else is a violation of the JSON contract you have between the publisher and consumer of this payload.